# Live camera feed with Iron Python on Visual Studio 2013

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, ironpython, emgucv

After about two days of testing and researching I've come up with nothing. I'm using IronPython through Visual Studio 2013 and I'm trying to get a camera view on the window. I can't seem to find any libraries that actually work with what I've got to do this.  There are lots of tutorials on setting different libraries up, and I've tried all the ones I can find, but without any luck because they don't seem to be exactly aimed at what I'm using. I've tried OpenCV but that doesn't seem to work, emgu is the closest I've got by doing this;

```
import clr
clr.AddReferenceToFile("Emgu.Util.dll")
clr.AddReferenceToFile("Emgu.CV.dll")
clr.AddReferenceToFile("Emgu.CV.ML.dll")
clr.AddReferenceToFile("Emgu.CV.UI.dll")
from Emgu.CV import *
from Emgu.CV.UI import *
from Emgu.CV.Structure import *
from System import *
```

And this seems to be the only method I've managed to get to work to do what I need, however, there's no API for python (Only VB.net, C#, etc.) so I have no idea what to do after this to get the camera to do anything.  So my question is pretty much, either, what do I need to do to get Emgu to give me the camera feed, or is there a better method that I've not found which works with IronPython and Visual Studio 2013?

Comment: You should be able to do anything you can do with C# and .NET in IronPython and .NET. There might be some situations where things get a bit awkward, but there is no need for a (Iron)Python specific API.

Comment: You're right, it is working, but it looks like I'm going to have to work everything out as I'm going along.  Or I could try learning C#.  Thanks for your help.